# Vectorize for loop with dict lookup

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have the following pandas dataframe and I would like to normalize the units to mg/kg by multiplying each row of the data column by an appropriate factor:

```
df
Out[28]: 
  analyte  data   unit
0       A  2.34  mg/kg
1       B  5.89  ng/kg
2       C  1.25  ug/kg
3       D  8.65  mg/kg
```

How would I vectorize the following code (as the real dataframe is somewhat larger):

```
units = {
        "mg/kg": 1,
        "ug/kg": 1e+3,
        "ng/kg": 1e+6
        }

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[index,'data'] = row['data'] * units[row['unit']]

df['unit'] = 'mg/kg'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can use [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) adnd [mul](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html):

```
df['data'] = df['unit'].map(units).mul(df['data'])
```